# Is there an OID to retrieve specific HDD partition on SNMP?

Tags: hard-drive, snmp, oid

I want to get hard disk free space of a specific partition, is there a way to retrieve this with SNMP OID? Is there any special OID for this?

---

**EDIT:**
the OID .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.9.1.7.1 refers to available space on the disk. How can get partition's free space? This is what I want.

Comment: `refers to available space on the disk. How can get partition's free space?` Does the disk have more than one partition?

Comment: @GregL I have /var /boot /etc and etc partitions... I want to get free space of /var partition

Comment: What's returned by an SNMP walk of `.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.9`?

Comment: @GregL the command `snmpwalk -Os -c public -v 1 127.0.0.1 .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.9` gives nothing but `End of MIB`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your case, partition layout and mount points your indexes can vary:
but here is example of reporting free disk space on partitions

two *mounted* partitions: 

`df  | grep mnt
/dev/xvdz1       5160576   10236   4888196   1% /mnt
/dev/xvdz2      36123264   49032  34239276   1% /mnt/test`

getting indexes for them from snmpwalk:

`snmpwalk -On  -v 2c -c public localhost .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.9  | grep  /dev/xvdz
.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.9.1.3.8 = STRING: "/dev/xvdz1"
.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.9.1.3.9 = STRING: "/dev/xvdz2"`

`8` and `9`  for `xvdz1` and `xvdz2` accordingly

so querying for free disk these indexes:

for `xvdz1`

 `# snmpwalk -On  -v 2c -c public localhost .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.9.1.7.8
.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.9.1.7.8 = INTEGER: 4888196`

for `xvdz2`

 `# snmpwalk -On  -v 2c -c public localhost .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.9.1.7.9
.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.9.1.7.9 = INTEGER: 34239276`

Compare it to output of `df`

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. At first `snmpwalk` shows OID `.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.9.1.3.8` and `.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.9.1.3.9`. But for `xvdz1` you have used `.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.9.1.7.8` is this a typo? or I don't get something very well. Tnx again.

Comment: `.8` and `.9` are just particular values for my example. xvdX is disk naming scheme for Xen (Amazon) replace it with sda or sdb or whatever you want to monitor.

Comment: Areza, yes it seems to be a typo -- by the common sense they they should match.  Possibly, @stimur copy pasted the first command but for some reason was typing the OIDs for the free disk query and unintentionally typed .1.7.8 instead of .1.3.8 at the end of the command.  In the last command it's likely that he just replaced the last digit without even verifying that the OID string points to a different location.

Comment: It is not a typo, `3.8` is of type string and shows the name of device mounted. While `1.8` is for free space on that partition.

Comment: Do `snmpwalk -On -v 2c -c public localhost .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.9` and see full output.